# Regex to redirect URL with question mark and ampersand, from page number to page title

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a redirect for the relative URL `index.php?route=product/product&product_id=74` to redirect to `products/myproduct/`

I'm very much a novice to regex. Here's the code I entered:

`RewriteRule ^index.php\?route=product\/product\&product_id=74/?$ products/myproduct/ [R=301,L]`

Clearly I messed up somehow because it's not redirecting to the right page (it just goes to the home page). How might I correct this code?

Comment: You'll notice I escaped the question mark and ampersand with backslashes.

Comment: You forgot to escape the dot in `index.php`.

Comment: Are you talking about a redirect or a rewrite?
`Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/product&product_id=74 products/myproduct/
`